# Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, Bluetooth file shareing

Tags: files, bluetooth, file-sharing, sharing

How is it possible to send an file for example in image to another phone with Bluetooth.

I managed to pair my phone with another phone through Bluetooth but I was not able to send an image file in that case with Bluetooth, I tried through the gallery but no success neither with the File Manager app.

Is there any other way or is this some bug?